# How do I get an old base off of an IPod 4 in ClashofClans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I remembered that I had an old IPod 4 with a high level base on it but it can’t get a new enough IOS to download the latest update is there any way for me to get the account onto a new device or is it gone for good

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing happen to me, and I just had to restart.  However, I did not have a Game Center account, and I believe that if you had CoC linked to a Game Center account, you can recover that base on another device signed in with that Game Center account.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a google account, sign into it on your iPod in settings > SuperCell Id. It should say it is disconnected. Once you have created an Id, on your other phone, log into it and you should have your old village on that device. :)